# IPv6 port scanners hang after scanning a closed port

Tags: ipv6, tcpdump, nftables, netcat

I am testing nftables firewall rules using two virtual machines, one with the active firewall and one that tries to connect to it.

For example with netcat and no firewall:

`nc -6 fe80::9d08:b3e2:47fa:2935%ens33 <any port>`

responds successfully with "connection refused" if no service is listening, but the port is open. And if I have netcat listening on the port on the other side, connection succeeds.

Then I add a firewall rule to drop everything except open port 33333:

`nc -6 fe80::9d08:b3e2:47fa:2935%ens33 33333`

and again connection refused/successful as expected.

Then I try a some other port that is dropped by the firewall default policy:

`nc -6 fe80::9d08:b3e2:47fa:2935%ens33 22222`

And netcat hangs until timeout, as expected I guess. But now to the problem: If I try again

`nc -6 fe80::9d08:b3e2:47fa:2935%ens33 33333`

it also hangs until timeout.

I have to flush the firewall rules, run netcat again successfully, re-apply firewall rules, and then it works again. Until I try to connect to closed port.

This happens only with IPv6. I tried `ncat` and `nmap` and `tcpdump` and all show similar weird behavior. No issues with IPv4.

There seems to be something I don't understand about IPv6 networking?

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**: The most likely explanation is that you dropped ICMPv6. Don't drop all of ICMPv6 unless you understand what precisely should still not be dropped.

During your tests, you have to insert a rule like:

```
meta l4proto ipv6-icmp accept
```

before the rules that drop other packets. The rule above could be refined, but that's out of the scope of this Q/A.

---

ICMPv6, among other roles (such as ping, time exceeded, ...) includes the equivalent role of IPv4's ARP: to resolve the link layer MAC address from the upper layer IPv6 address with the Neighbor Discovery Protocol ([NDP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neighbor_Discovery_Protocol)). While ARP is not firewalled in the `ip` family but in the `arp` family, NDP, part if ICMPv6 does get firewalled by the `ip6` (or the `inet`) family. If all is dropped, then NDP is dropped.

The way cache revalidation occurs, once a neighbor entry naturally switches from REACHABLE to the STALE state after a few seconds, it can still be used without confirmation especially when traffic happens. After some time it switches to the PROBE state which then requires an NDP confirmation, switching back to REACHABLE. So one kind of state flow is:

```
REACHABLE -> STALE -> PROBE -> REACHABLE
```

Depending on traffic there are other possibilities. Details are available in [RFC 4861](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4861.html). The STALE state can exist for a very long time when there's no traffic:

> From the perspective of correctness, there is no need to periodically
> purge Destination and Neighbor Cache entries. Although **stale**
> information can potentially **remain in the cache indefinitely**, the
> Neighbor Unreachability Detection algorithm ensures that stale
> information is **purged quickly if it is actually being used**.

During the STALE and PROBE states, the old entry is given the benefit of the doubt: it can still be used to send traffic. This stops when NDP fails a few seconds later: the destination is now in FAILED state and the MAC address is deleted from the cache.

If you disable all traffic, you also disable NDP traffic and lose IPv6 connectivity very quickly (including global IPv6).

This explains all of your symptoms:

- you made a attempt without rules: NDP successfully happened and client's NDP cache went in state REACHABLE and then possibly switched to state STALE which can hang around a long time
- ruleset was installed, dropping NDP attempts. If there's no traffic, the client's NDP cache can stay in STALE state for a very long time.
- the first test on TCP 33333 used the STALE cache entry and succeeded. Observed return traffic might even delay the switch to PROBE state (so this first test can probably be repeated successfully for several seconds).
- the next test either did not manage to reach the target before the entry switched to PROBE state (NDP failed) and then to FAILED state (which deleted the MAC address), or managed this but was then anyway blocked as TCP 22222 traffic is blocked by the drop-all rule. Repeated attempts (incl. TCP SYN retries) without reply will speed up the switch to PROBE state.
- sooner or later the neighbor cache will have switched to PROBE and then FAILED state.
- the last test to TCP 33333 has no known MAC address to send IPv6 frames to: it can't succeed.

There's also a minor observed behavior difference when using an IPv6 link-layer address as destination here: when trying to reach a link-layer address (ie: an fe80::/10 address), contrary to an IPv6 global address destination or for the IPv4 case, it appears the client doesn't fail 3s later with `EHOSTUNREACH` (No route to host): nothing happens for the client at all to warn it (tested with `strace`).

So there's no way to distinguish if the failure is caused by NDP failure(which is an unintended effect) or by the remaining parts of the firewall: one might think the firewall suddenly behaves incorrectly, while it did not. The state changes in the NDP cache can take up to 30s.

This can be checked by using on the (Linux) client:

```
ip -6 neigh show fe80::9d08:b3e2:47fa:2935 dev ens33
```

which will likely display in the end:

```
fe80::9d08:b3e2:47fa:2935 dev ens33 FAILED
```

State change can be tracked in real-time with:

```
ip -ts -6 monitor neigh dev ens33
```